How does Nicepool die?
In Deadpool & Wolverine, there are many versions of Deadpools from different universes; there is an epic battle between Deadpool and Wolverine and a large group of Deadpools, including a female Deadpool and a baby Deadpool. Before the battle starts, Nicepool (a good looking / unmasked Deadpool) gets shot and eventually killed.
I am wondering how could he die? As we can see at the end of this epic battle, all Deadpools can resurrect themselves. Why is Nicepool the only one who cannot be resurrected?

It's clear from the dialogue that Nicepool doesn't regenerate like Deadpool.
This is probably related to his appearance, since he does not have Wade's cancer scars, he never went through the mutation-triggering process in the first movie, and therefore never gained superpowers.

Deadpool: How long does it take for you to regenerate?
Nicepool: Regenerate?

Later

Deadpool: How was I supposed to know he doesn’t regenerate?


Well, I'm pretty sure he wouldn't last this long without any superpowers. Talking after all these shots to the chest is no mean feat :p
